# How to add label and title to matplotlib animation

Tags: python-3.x

I am not able to add label and title to matplotlib animation.
Please find my code below

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style
import time
%matplotlib inline
style.use("ggplot")
fig = plt.figure() 
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

def animate(i): 
    pullData = open("twitter-out.txt","r").read()
    lines = pullData.split('\n')

xar = []
yar = []
x = 0
y = 0

for l in lines[-200:]:
    x += 1
    if "pos" in l:
        y += 1
    elif "neg" in l:
        y -= 1

    xar.append(x)
    yar.append(y)

ax1.clear()
ax1.plot(xar,yar)
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work. Label and title is your last problem here. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Hi Alperen, I checked my code works fine. In order to view plot, you need to have the data. If you know how to add labels to an animation of matplotlib. Please reply.

Comment: Hi, I don't know the exact answer, but I can try. However, I can't run your code. I'm aware it needs data file `twitter-out.txt`. But: **1)** What is `%matplotlib inline`? **2)** `lines`is not defined before for loop. If you have answers for these, and share an example data for `twitter-out.txt`, I can try to help you.

Comment: Hey alperen,  %matplotlib inline is used in jupyter notebook. I have defined the lines too. I figured out how to add labels .

Comment: I'm happy for you. If you figured out, you can answer your own question. Then, it can help other users.